# redmine installation not working through nginx and thin

Tags: nginx, redmine, thin

I've installed Redmine on an Ubuntu 13.04 server.
This installation worked fine and I confirmed Redmine was working through the WEBrick server (as per redmine documentation).

To make things more stable I want to run Redmine behind Nginx & Thin.

With this part I run into problems as Nginx reports getting timeouts:

```
2013/07/19 07:47:32 [error] 1051#0: *10 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, .......
```

Thin Configuration:

```
---
chdir: /home/redmine/app/redmine
environment: production
address: 127.0.0.1
port: 3000
timeout: 5
log: log/thin.log
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
max_conns: 128
max_persistent_conns: 64
require: []
wait: 10
servers: 1
daemonize: true
```

I can see Thin is running, the pid file is created and a logfile is started.
I see no further additions to the logfile when doing requests.

Nginx configuration:

```
upstream redmine {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
        server_name redmine.my.domain;
        listen 443;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /home/redmine/sites/redmine/certificates/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/redmine/sites/redmine/certificates/server.key;

        access_log /home/redmine/sites/redmine/logs/server.access.nginx.log;
        error_log /home/redmine/sites/redmine/logs/server.error.nginx.log;

        root /home/redmine/app/redmine;

        location / {
                try_files $uri @ruby;
        }

        location @ruby {
                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_read_timeout 5;
                proxy_pass http://redmine;
        }
}
```

I can see additions to the Nginx log.

Can anyone give me a hint on where to find the problem in this?

Current result of `iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:3000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: what does error log tell ?

Comment: Nginx error log line is on top of the post.

Comment: both thin.3000.log and production.log in redmine dir log startup messages. Then nothing more is added.

Comment: i see. Try to telnet the port

Comment: "telnet 127.0.0.1 3000" keeps on trying (probably a timeout).

Comment: that's the reason. Try to set to other port.

Comment: Changed Thin to port 3123; same result with telnet. Changed iptables default INPUT policy to ACCEPT (was DROP) and it connects. Do you happen to know what iptables lines to add to get this working with a default drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because your firewall "iptables" blocked the port.

Rollback your iptables config, then issue the follow command:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 3123 -j ACCEPT
```

Remember to save the setting by:

```
service iptables save
```

More information about iptables: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

p.s. `sudo` may be needed for the above commands.

Comment: didn't help. Still unable to telnet in. Also, wouldn't that open the port for the whole world? instead of just locally? I've added the result of `iptables -L` to the original question.

Comment: added `lo` as constraints of localhost traffic only

Comment: Fixed the problem after some further unrelated issues. Tnx for the help!